# RSpec rails return wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I try test with RSpec my example doesn`t want to work, because post_categories_url return wrong path. Need  "/categories/2", but I get "/2/categories"

```
  describe "GET /show" do
    it "renders a successful response" do
      post_category = PostCategory.create! valid_attributes
      puts post_categories_url(post_category)
      binding.pry
      get post_categories_url(post_category)
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
```

My routes:

```
  ...
  get '/:locale' => 'welcome#index'
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ru/ do
    get '/user/:id' => 'users#show', as: 'user'
    get '/users' => 'users#index'
    resources :post_categories, path: 'categories'
    resources :posts, path: 'adv'
  ...
```

Comment: show the output of `rails routes | grep 'post'`

Comment: Show how the route is defined. Telling us it's "wrong" doesn't mean much, when you have not provided the means for us to verify what is "right".

Comment: I added to the question

Comment: You could read https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs. `get :show, params: { id: post_category.id }  ` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot and I did not work so closely with routes for a while.

You have this constraint defined on a route:

```
locale: /en|ru/
```

And if I recall correctly, the router will check constraints when you try to access it, so `2/categories` will not be found in routes.

And **most probably** the link helper **will not check constraints** when composing an URL or path, so it might think that first param is `:locale`.

You can quickly check if that's the case by adding `locale` option in the URL helper:

```
 post_categories_url(post_category, locale: 'en')
 # should give ../en/categories/2 if I'm guessing right.
```

Assuming I'm right at all, it's not obvious how you should fix it in your case. Maybe explicit `locale:`  when generating URLs is fine? Maybe [defining a default locale](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults) would work?